# how to coorelate multiple values in array with certain name in other array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to make an all text RPG game in python with cmd, but I need to find a way to place dungeons on certain X and Y.

I've tried creating two different arrays :

```
placesYX = [[50, 100]]
places = ['First Door']
```

and then making a function where it would check each time

```
if x == placesYX[0][0] and y == placesYX[0][1]:
        print('you are at: ', places[0])
```

but I cannot repeat this for each place I add, I need a function that checks if x and y both match any values in placesXY and if it is true:

```
print('You are at: ', places[mathcingplace])
```

thank you to anyone who answers(I'm a beginner)

Answer (score 0):

You could use python's enumerate functionality to keep track of both the index of your places, and the value:

```
placesXY = [[50, 100], [75, 150]]
places = ['First Door', 'Second Door']

def check_place(x, y):
    for index, coordinates in enumerate(placesXY):
        if coordinates[0] == x and coordinates[0] == y:
            return f"You are at: {places[index]}"
```

`enumerate` lets you keep track of both index in the list, as well as value in the list.

`f"some string {variable}"` lets you (f)ormat a string with variables, and you can print f strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: You might step back and reconsider the way you are modeling the data. If you need to frequently look things up given a tuple of `(x,y)` values, you could consider making a dictionary keyed to coordinates instead of separate lists.

For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
# defaultdict will allow you to set global default when there's nothing at a coord

placesYX = [(50, 100), (90, 200)]
place_names = ['First Door', 'some creature']
places = dict(zip(placesYX, place_names))
# places looks like
# {(50, 100): 'First Door', (90, 200): 'some creature'}

# now you can lookup directly:
places[(50, 100)] # first door
places[(90, 200)] # some creature
```

If it's possible you will look up coordinates that aren't in the dictionary, you can use:

```
places.get((0,0), "some default value")
```

to avoid a key error.